# Select a particular HTML table with JSOUP

Tags: java, html, dom, jsoup

I have my code as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://ms.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaysia").get();
    org.jsoup.select.Elements rows = doc.select("tr");
    for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element row : rows) {
        org.jsoup.select.Elements columns = row.select("td");
        for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element column : columns) {
            System.out.print(column.text());
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

It is printing out all the table rows that on the webpage, is it possible if I just want to print out a selected table in the website?

Comment: Assuming you have browser with dev. tools. Lookup table element and copy CSS selector.You're done.

Comment: @rkosegi sry, I'm new to java, what is dev means?

Comment: Chrome DevTools (right-click on webpage and select Inspect): https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

Comment: Firefox right click and select Inspect Element.

Comment: off tangent suggestion here, clean up your imports :)

```import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is grab the table by its title.  Since the title is embedded in a cousin element of the table, and CSS has no parent selector, you can use a combination of CSS and Jsoup API calls to achieve this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://ms.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaysia").get();
    Element table = doc.select("span#Trivia").parents().first().nextElementSibling();
    Elements rows = table.select("tr");
    for (Element row : rows) {
        String header = row.select("th").text();
        String value = row.select("td").text();
        System.out.println(header + ": " + value);
    }
}
```

Comment: yup, your code can produce the output i want, but it's just print out the 2nd column only. how about the first column?

Comment: Yes, the first columns are `th` headers, so I've updated the code to print those too.

Comment: thx, now it working perfectly, is that possible to print out the border too?

Comment: If you want the table borders, it sounds like you want to generate an image instead of just extracting text.  If that is the case, please make a new question because that is quite a bit more involved.

Comment: I write Web-Scraping software for foreign news websites.  Just so you know, **Wikipedia** is on the list of **Java-Script Heavy** - meaning scraping the page won't always get you the content that is displayed in ... say... a Google Chrome Web-Browser.   After the page loads, a lot of the paragraphs inside the Wikipedia Article are populated by Java-Script - _**post-download fashion**_

Comment: @RalphTorello That's a good point.  Jsoup will not work for dynamically loaded sites; Selenium Webdriver is a better tool in that case because it runs an actual browser instance which can execute JavaScript.  Luckily for this particular page, the particular table in question is delivered with the initial HTML payload.

Comment: @RalphTorello : you can also load "mobile" version of wikipedia (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaysia) which is not so JS heavy.

Answer (score 2):

Try to select a particular table element first and then loop over its nested elements.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://ms.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaysia").get();
    Element table = doc.select("table.wikitable").get(1);
    Elements body = table.select("tbody");
    Elements rows = body.select("tr");
    for (Element row : rows) {
        System.out.print(row.select("th").text());
        System.out.print(row.select("td").text());
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Ibu negaraKuala Lumpur
Pusat pentadbiranPutrajaya
Tarikh Hari Kebangsaan31 Ogos 1957
Cogan Kata NegaraBersekutu Bertambah Mutu
BenuaAsia, Asia Tenggara
Koordinat Geografi2 30 U, 112 30 T
Jumlah hujan tahunan2000mm ~ 2500mm
IklimTropika dengan suhu 24–35 Darjah Celsius
Bunga kebangsaanBunga Raya
Binatang rasmiHarimau
Puncak tertinggiGunung Kinabalu, Banjaran Crocker (4175m)
Puncak tertinggi SemenanjungGunung Tahan, Banjaran Tahan (2187 m)
Banjaran terpanjangBanjaran Titiwangsa (500 km)
Sungai terpanjangSungai Rajang, Sarawak (563 km)
Sungai terpanjang di SemenanjungSungai Pahang (475 km)
Jambatan terpanjangJambatan Pulau Pinang (13.5 km)
Gua terbesarGua Niah, Sarawak
Bangunan tertinggiMenara Berkembar Petronas (452m)
Negeri terbesarSarawak (124,450 km persegi)
Negeri terkecilPerlis (810 km persegi)
Tempat paling lembapBukit Larut (lebih 5080 mm)
Tempat paling keringJelebu (kurang daripada 1500 mm)
Kawasan paling padatKuala Lumpur (6074/km², 15,543/batu persegi)
Penanaman eksport utamaKelapa sawit dan getah
```

Read more documentation [here](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) about JSOUP.

Comment: org.jsoup.select.Elements rows = doc.select("table[class=wikitable]");
this selected exactly that table.

Comment: Updated code with better selector as suggested by @özkanpakdil

Comment: @Choy I fixed class name. I was looking at table on the top right of the page :)

Comment: @Choy Try now. I am getting: 
```Ibu negaraKuala Lumpur
Pusat pentadbiranPutrajaya
Tarikh Hari Kebangsaan31 Ogos 1957
Cogan Kata NegaraBersekutu Bertambah Mutu
BenuaAsia, Asia Tenggara
Koordinat Geografi2 30 U, 112 30 T
Jumlah hujan tahunan2000mm ~ 2500mm
IklimTropika dengan suhu 24–35 Darjah Celsius
...
...
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181680/discussion-between-nabster-and-choy).

Comment: The problem with this code is that it relies on the index of the table.  If tables are added or removed from the page, the script might break.

Comment: @JoeCoder Can you elaborate on how does this guarantee that it will always get right table, 2nd in this case? `.parents().first().nextElementSibling()`

Comment: It selects the table by its title rather than index.  The title element is a "cousin" of the table in the HTML hierarchy, so we select the title first with `span#Trivia`.  Then we grab its parent element, and then the "next-sibling" in the HTML hierarchy is the target table.